# Unix tail and grep equivalent for Windows

Tags: powershell, batch-file

We have the following unix command:

```
/usr/bin/tail -n 1 %{path} | grep --silent -F "%{message}" && rm -f %{path}%
```

This:

1. `/usr/bin/tail -n 1 %{path}` gets the last line in the file that the `path` variable refers to
2. `| grep --silent -F "%{message}"` pipes the output to another command, `grep`, which checks if the output of the previous command is equal to the value of `message`
3. `&& rm -f %{path}%` if the values are equal, then delete the file refered to by `path`

The above line is in a configuration file which is allows for calls to be made to the underlying operating system.

I want to replicate the functionalirty on windows.
I tried this:

```
command => 'powershell -Command "& {Get-Item $args[0] | ? { (Get-Content $_ -Tail 1).Contains($args[1]) }| Remove-Item -Force}" "'%path%'" "'%message%'"'
```

This error is thrown:

```
Error: Expected one of #, {, } at line 15, column 131 (byte 498)
```

Line 15 is the line in the configuration file which contains the above.

Thanks

Comment: If you can't install Linux, or other decent OS, maybe borrow the tools from one :-)   http://unxutils.sourceforge.net

Comment: do not download anything from sourceforge - http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/05/sourceforge-grabs-gimp-for-windows-account-wraps-installer-in-bundle-pushing-adware/

Comment: You'd better use a Powershell script to do all this work together. If you need a multipurpose grep/tail then yes, take Windows ports of grep and tail, if not, you can make a Powershell script and use `Select-Object -last 1`, then run a regexp match against the string received, then use del if you've received a valid path.

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell solution:

```
$path    = 'C:\path\to\your.txt'
$message = 'message'

Get-Item $path | ? { (Get-Content $_ -Tail 1).Contains($message) } | Remove-Item -Force
```

If you want to run it from a command line, call it like this:

```
powershell -Command "& {Get-Item $args[0] | ? { (Get-Content $_ -Tail 1).Contains($args[1]) } | Remove-Item -Force}" "'C:\path\to\your.txt'" "'message'"
```

Comment: Thanks. Running as entered in your example, I get this: The term 'C:\Program' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function..,, or the term 'C:\Windows\System32' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function ...

Comment: @user1052610 Try adding nested single quotes to the arguments. See updated answer.

Comment: It's saying:Error: Expected one of #, {, } at line 13, column 134 (byte 466) after input {,   ----column 133 is after Remove-Item -Force}"

Comment: @user1052610 There is no line 13 in my sample code. Please update your question with the code you currently have and the exact error message it's throwing.

Comment: @user1052610 Please specify your environment/tool. You're apparently not running this from either batch/CMD or PowerShell. The cause of your problem is most likely that you're using single quotes inside a single-quoted string, which prematurely terminate the string, thus causing the error. Stuff inside single-quoted strings normally can't be escaped, so you may have to replace the outer single quotes with double quotes and escape all double quotes inside the string. How that's done depends on what tool you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tailhead.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/fileUtils/tailHead.bat) (pure batch script utility) that can be used to show lasts/fists lines of a file.Instead of `Grep` you can use `findstr` or `find` :

```
tailhead.bat tailhead -file=%pathToFile% -begin=-3|find  "%message%"
```

Comment: Thanks, but where arwe find and findstr defined? The command prompt does not recognize either one of them, so how wouldf they work in the example you give?

Comment: @user1052610 - findstr and find are build in windows.Check the output of `echo %path%` command.There you should have `C:\windows\system32`

Comment: Thanks, added to the path and now find is recognized. Is this the correct way to end the command:  && del %pathToFile% ? Tried && del myFileName,txt as a test, but that did not work.

Comment: @user1052610 if you put `&& del "%pathToFile%"` it will be deleted if the %message% is presented.