# is it possible to open a new cmd window with a batch file and use the new window as i live log?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have created a batch file to help me write a script for an application I have on my phone that will automate touch tasks. The script I am creating will require 240x9 lines of the scripting language to complete the tasks I am wanting to complete, is there a way to open a new cmd line and output text to the new window?

So for instance right now I have each option in the batch file to write the screen touch coordinates required by the scripting language to execute my tasks out to a text file like this.

```
@ECHO :start>speedsearch.txt
```

Is it possible to pass these to a new window just to use it as a live log so if I loose my place I can refer to the log window to remind myself where I am in the creation of my script?

i do know that in a regular cmd window if i were to use.

```
TYPE C:\speedSearch.txt
```

it will print what is in the text file, so is there anyway to pass the command from my batch script to.

```
TYPE C:\speedSearch.txt
```

everytime i choose an option to add a line to the script in the file?
i already have the new window opening by using this at the beginning of my script.

```
start "LOGGING WINDOW" C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CMD.EXE
```

I just need a little help with how i pass commands to the new window, without disrupting my current session in the batch script.

Comment: Use [Unix tail and grep equivalent for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31136733) (without the search part) in the second window to read the log and output text when it's changed.

Comment: You could also use the `waitfor` command to send a signal from one thread to the other alerting it that it's time to read the log file and output newly added lines.  The `tail` solution would be easier, but `waitfor` would work without requiring 3rd party tools.

Comment: Can you give an example on wait for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is about *synchronization*. There are several ways to start two or more execution threads in Batch files and exist several standard ways to solve the usual synchro problems. The difference in this case is that the second thread is started via a `start` command, so there is no way to redirect its standard input. The only way to accurately detect the end of the file in the second thread is inserting a particular line that indicate that point; in the code below, ":EOF" string is used for this purpose.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if "%~1" neq "" goto %1

echo :start> speedsearch.txt
rem Run View Log code simultaneously with Main code
start "View Log" "%~NX0" ViewLog

:Main
   set "line="
   set /P "line=Enter next line: "
   if not defined line goto endMain
   echo %line%>> speedsearch.txt
goto Main
:endMain
rem Send the "end of file" mark
echo :EOF>> speedsearch.txt
echo File complete
goto :EOF


:ViewLog
set i=0
call :Update < speedsearch.txt 
goto :EOF

:Update
   set "line="
   set /P "line="
   if "!line!" equ ":EOF" goto :EOF
   if defined line (
      set /A i+=1
      echo !i!- !line!
   )
goto :Update
```